# How to get absolute path of a directory?

Tags: linux, bash

I want to automate the following thing:

cd into current directory

```
cd workdir
```

make a new directory

```
mkdir mydata
```

and get the absolute path to this mydata directory

Comment: Either that or `$(pwd)/mydata`.

Comment: Note that `PWD` doesn't necessarily expand to the absolute path (in case you're in a symlink directory). Note that `$(pwd)` will trim trailing newlines if you're in a directory the name of which contains trailing newlines (that's a funny joke to do).

Comment: @gniourf_gniourf - The question was phrased in terms of "absolute path", which normally means "a path from the root" (see e.g. wikipedia), and generally also means "without embedded . or .. subpaths".  The question is also phrased in term of "workdir" and "mydata", rather than $workdir and $mydata, the difference being that the former suggests a reasonably normal directory name specification.

Answer (score 6):

There is a Unix utility that can achieve that:

```
readlink --canonicalize nameofyourfileorfolder
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming *cd workdir; mkdir mydata* does not fail:

```
dir=$(cd workdir; mkdir mydata; pwd)
```

Slightly more robust:

```
dir=$(mkdir -p workdir/mydata; pwd)
```

For a still more robust approach, you could run the following command after checking the created directory exists:

```
dir=$(cd workdir/mydata; pwd)
```

If by "absolute path" you mean the physical path, then consider using *pwd -P* instead of just *pwd*.

Comment: Not quite _robust_: fails if directory name contains trailing newlines, and doesn't necessarily indicate absolute path (in case you're in symlink dirs). The latter can be fixed by using `cd -P`. The former can be fixed using `read` appropriately.